# Motorola Android ICS R2 eclipse addon download

Tags: android, eclipse, add-on, motorola

Does anyone know how to download BluetoothGatt.jar & BluetoothGattService.jar ? They are in the add-on package from Motorola for eclipse, but the website is already down.
This was the origin:
http://www.motorola.com/sites/motodev/us-en/motodev_lp.html

Comment: Note that `BluetoothGatt` and related classes were added to Android 4.3: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html

Comment: Yes i know, but i have 4.1.2 which does not have support for GATT, that's why external libs could help.

Answer (score 0):

The MOTODEV site (and team) were removed after the Google acquisition was official.  The open-source Eclipse plugin code was submitted and accepted into the AOSP in the platform/tools/motodev repo.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/motodev/

However, those jars were proprietary and are not in the repo. They aren't in my installed version of MOTODEV Studio 4.0 (the last release).  I suspect they were in one of the addons that were once accessible through the SDK Manager.  The server for the Motorola addons was decommissioned around the same time.  I didn't keep any of those files, but I'm sure they're on a backup somewhere.  Have you tried to use the Motorola Support Forums?  MattG used to forward developer requests to us from time to time.  If he's still around, he might be able to help you locate those libraries.  Or try XDA...

Good luck